# How do I iron-fortify homemade baby cereal?

Tags: vitamins, baby-food

I have been making baby cereal powder by grinding rolled oats, flax seed, and hemp seed into a powder. I prepare this cereal by adding water and heat.

Many commercial powdered baby cereals (and general breakfast cereals) are iron-fortified.

What can I add to my homemade dry powder to fortify it with iron?

***Note:*** Please hold off posting any opinions. I'm looking for factual answers with links to reference data.

Comment: I'd like to remind everybody that we have stricter rules about nutrition related topics than about others. Specifically, please don't discuss (in comments or answers) whether one should fortify, whether different forms of fortification are biologically better than others, etc. The answers should focus on how to achieve the physical presence of iron in the food, regardless of its effects.

Answer (score 2):

Whole grain contains more iron than the more processed grain. So that might help. Seeds and nuts also contain a lot of iron. While nuts in themselves are a choking hazard for babies, ground nuts mixed with the rest of the stuff you grind should be no problem.

Comment: Sorry Galastel, but your original version included off topic information. We have to remove either that paragraph, or delete the whole answer.